# Using makefile to merge javascript files after compiled from coffeescript

Tags: javascript, linux, makefile, coffeescript

I have 2 files. `./main.coffee` and `./shared.coffee`. I'd like to use makefile to compile both then concatinate it into `./main.js`.

This is what I currently have:

```
public: main.min.js


main.min.js: main.js
uglifyjs ./main.js > ./main.min.js

#combine the shared files with the compiled main.coffee
main.js: ./main.coffee
coffee -c ./main.coffee #problem1
cat ./main.js ./shared.js > ./main.js

shared: ./shared.coffee
coffee -c ./shared.coffee
```

I know this will give an error for the `cat` operator. How do I just compile and pass the contents from the line labeled `problem1` to the cat method without generating main.js from it.

For eg. the coffeescript site gave this: `Pipe in CoffeeScript to STDIN and get back JavaScript over STDOUT. Good for use with processes written in other languages. An example:
cat src/cake.coffee | coffee -sc` how do I combine this method with cat to just merge the files?

Comment: See [coffee --join](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [coffee --join](http://jashkenas.github.com/coffee-script/#usage):

```
main.js:
coffee -c -j main.js main.coffee shared.coffee
```

**Edit:** As Trevor Burnham notes, this is not exactly the same as what the asker wanted:

> --join first merges main.coffee and shared.coffee, then compiles the merged source. This means that you don't get scope separation.

Comment: This is actually different from what the asker wanted: `--join` first merges `main.coffee` and `shared.coffee`, then compiles the merged source. This means that you don't get scope separation.

Comment: Trevor: True, adding this caveat to the answer.